# How can make manually define color code in open xml C#.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml

I could create a Google Pie Chart but where exporting to MS Word there only the default colour of MS Word. Then, How can create manually define the color code in open xml style? Below I have added c# code when export button click event is fired.

```
  protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  

    CreateWordChart createWordChart = null;
    try
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        string p = @"E:/File/Graph" + r.Next(1, 20000) + ".docx";
        FileStream fs = File.Create(p);
        fs.Close();       

        createWordChart = new CreateWordChart(p);
        List<ChartSubArea> chartAreas = new List<ChartSubArea>();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.0.0.101; uid=sa; pwd=sql;database=QuestionDB;");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        string cmdstr = "select top 5 First_name, COUNT(Department) [Department] from Employee group by First_name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(ds);           
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));


        System.Drawing.Color[] colorSet = new System.Drawing.Color[4] { System.Drawing.Color.Red, System.Drawing.Color.Blue, System.Drawing.Color.Green, System.Drawing.Color.Purple };


        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        string cat = "";
        string val = "";
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            cat = dr[0].ToString();
            val = dr[1].ToString();

            chartAreas.Add(new ChartSubArea() { ColorDra = *colorSet*, Label = cat, Value = val });            
            i = i + 1;
        }
        createWordChart.CreateChart(chartAreas);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (createWordChart != null)
        {
            createWordChart.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

 public class ChartSubArea
{
    public System.Drawing.Color[] ColorDra { get; set; }
    public Shading purecolor { get; set; }
    public SchemeColorValues Color { get; set; }
    public String Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks Advance.